# javascript setTimeout function does not behave normally after 1 call

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setinterval

I have the following function :

```
function loadInfoBubble(aString)
        {
            $('#infoBubble').html('<h3>info :</h3><p>'+aString+'</p>');
            infoBubble.style.display = "block";

            var opacity = 9;
            var vanishBlock = null;

            var theTimeOut = setTimeout(function()
            {
                vanishBlock = setInterval(function()
                {
                    if(opacity > 0)
                    {
                        opacity--;
                    }
                    infoBubble.style.opacity = "0."+opacity;
                }, 100);
            }, 7000); 

            var theTimeOut2 = setTimeout(function()
            {
                infoBubble.style.display = "none";
                clearInterval(vanishBlock);
            }, 9000);

        }
```

This function is linked to a button by an onclick event.
The function is supposed to display a block which contains a sentence for 9 seconds, and after 7 seconds it starts to vanish.

It behaves normally for the first call, but if I click several times, it doesn't work anymore, even if I let the timeOuts end.

I don't understand why because each timeout or interval belongs to its own variable.

Comment: Define your global variables outside the function.

Comment: You never reset the opacity of the element back to 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code never resets the opacity back to 1. Also, if you trigger the action again before a cycle is finished, the previous cycle isn't canceled. Thus if you trigger the bubble, and then trigger it again 5 seconds later, the first cycle will still run and the bubble will disappear in only 2 seconds. If you click *again*, the bubble will be faded by the cycle that started on the second click.

I think what you need to do is save the timer references with the bubble object itself, and then reset everything when you want to start a display cycle. You can use the jQuery `.data()` method for that:

```
function loadInfoBubble(aString) {
  var $bubble = $("#infoBubble");
  $bubble
    .html('<h3>info :</h3><p>' + aString + '</p>')
    .css({ display: "block", opacity: 1 });

  var opacity = 9;

  var timers = $bubble.data("timers") || {};
  clearInterval(timers.vanishBlock);
  clearTimeout(timers.showTimer);
  clearTimeout(timers.clearTimer);

  timers = {
    showTimer: setTimeout(function() {
      timers.vanishBlock = setInterval(function() {
        if (opacity > 0) {
          opacity--;
        }
        $bubble.css({ opacity: "0." + opacity });
      }, 100);
    }, 7000),
    clearTimer: setTimeout(function() {
      $bubble.css({ display:  "none" });
      clearInterval(timers.vanishBlock);
    }, 9000)
  };
  $bubble.data("timers", timers);
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/49ekrxqt/1/)